# Change Style of text cursor with CSS (or JS)

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the look of the text cursor in an input field on my html page? There are multiple options for the mouse cursor, but I am looking to change the text cursor. Is there a possibility, maybe with CSS (or JS)?

Comment: You can change the color with [caret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color).

Comment: What do you mean the text cursor?  If you only want to change the cursor while it is in a textbox, target the textboxes: `input[type="text"]{cursor: pointer;}`.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge that's not changeable. Would love for someone to prove me wrong. You can color it, however...

Comment: @BryceHowitson, I guess you could "fake it to make it". Have a div styled to look like an input and an actual input hidden off screen. When the div gets focus, give focus to the input and on keyup of the input use that text to add to the div. And at the end of the line have whatever character you want for the cursor. it's not perfect by no means as it doesn't take into consideration the user clicking inside existing inputted text though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to change anything but the color of the text cursor. To change the color set the caret-color property on the input element.

```
input[type="text"]{
 caret-color: red;
}
```